Android OAuth 2.0 Client can't verify app ownership
I am trying to verify app ownership in OAuth client in Google Cloud Console -> APIs & Services -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. But I get the error "This client is not applicable to verify ownership because it's not a Google Play Store app", regardless of which Android OAuth client I'm using with the SHA-1 of google play app signing key or release key. What could be causing this?

I have the Admin role, but the account with the Owner role had the same problem. The app was published on Google Play years ago.

I think the error means your OAuth 2.0 Client you’re trying to use to verify app ownership is not recognized as being associated with any Google Play app or the published app you mentioned.
You mentioned that the app was published on Google Play years ago, you can try referring to this documentation for another way to verify your App ownership. As per the documentation, the Android app ownership verification is only available for Google Play apps. You can also check these steps on how to authenticate your client using Play App Signing.
This OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps documentation might be a good read and can be helpful for you.

Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I am doing everything according to the documentation.
I even tried to get SHA-1 directly from the apk.
The interesting thing is that it printed 2 of my certificates: Signer (minSdkVersion=33, maxSdkVersion=2147483647) and Signer (minSdkVersion=24, maxSdkVersion=32). One of them has SHA-1 of App Signing Certificate from Google Play and the other has SHA-1 of the Legacy App Signing Certificate, which is no longer in use.
In any case, Google Sign In doesn't work no matter Android version.

Have you tried reaching out to Google Cloud Support or Google Play Help Center? They have a dedicated support team that might help you more in addressing your concern, as they can offer additional insights and troubleshooting steps.
